# How to get count of average calls every 5 minutes using datetime sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, qsqlquery

I am running the following query

```
select DateTime
from Calls
where DateTime > '17 Oct 2018 00:00:00.000' and
      DialedNumberID = '1234'
```

What would this give me is a list of all the times that this number was dialled on the specific date.

[image: pic here:]

Essentially what I am looking for is a query that would give me the average calls that take place every X minutes and would like to run the query for the whole year.

Thanks

Comment: And what would the result look like? One single number representing the average amount of calls made within X minutes?

Comment: And where are you stuck? Which problem are you facing you need an answer for from us?

Comment: yes a single number  , but the query didnt work

Comment: select count(*) / timestampdiff(minute, date '2018-01-01', now()) * 5 as avg_calls
from calls
where `DateTime` >= date '2018-01-01'
and DialedNumberID = 1234;

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @SalmanA your query worked just need the average number of calls from your second colum ( a single number)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a table named `Calls` with the columns `DateTime` and `DialedNumberID`.

You can summarize the information in that table year-by-year using the kind of pattern.

```
  SELECT YEAR(`DateTime`),
         DialedNumberID,
         COUNT(*) call_count
    FROM Calls
   GROUP BY YEAR(`DateTime`), DialedNumberID
```

The trick in this pattern is to `GROUP BY f(date)` . The function `f()` reduces any date to the year in which it occures.

Summary by five minute intervals, you need `f(date)` that reduces datestamps to five minute intervals.  That function is a good deal more complex than `YEAR()`.

```
DATE_FORMAT(datestamp,'%Y-%m-%d %H:00') + INTERVAL (MINUTE(datestamp) - MINUTE(datestamp) MOD 5)
```

Given, for example, `2001-09-11 08:43:00`, this gives back `2001-09-11 08:40:00`.

So, here's your summary by five minute intervals.

```
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`DateTime`,'%Y-%m-%d %H:00')+INTERVAL(MINUTE(`DateTime`)-MINUTE(datestamp) MOD 5) interval_beginning,
         DialedNumberID,
         COUNT(*) call_count
    FROM Calls
   GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`DateTime`,'%Y-%m-%d %H:00')+INTERVAL(MINUTE(`DateTime`)-MINUTE(datestamp) MOD 5),
           DialedNumberID
```

You can make this query clearer and less repetitive by defining a stored function for that ugly `DATE_FORMAT()` expression. But that's a topic for another day.

Finally, append

```
  WHERE YEAR(`DateTime`) = YEAR(NOW())
    AND DialedNumberID = '1234'
```

to the query to filter by the current year and a particular id.

This query will need work to make it as efficient as possible. That too is a topic for another day.

**Pro tip:**  `DATETIME` is a reserved word in MySQL. Column names are generally case-insensitive. Avoid naming your columns, in this case `DateTime`, the same as a reserved word.

Answer (score 0):

The average amount of calls per interval is the number of calls (`COUNT(*)`) divided by the minutes between the start and end of of the monitored period (`TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute, period_start, period_end)`) multiplied with the number of minutes in the desired interval (five in your example).

For MySQL:

```
select count(*) / timestampdiff(minute, date '2018-01-01', now()) * 5 as avg_calls
from calls
where `datetime` >= date '2018-01-01'
and dialednumberid = 1234;
```

For SQL Server:

```
select count(*) * 1.0 / datediff(minute, '20180101', getdate()) * 5 as avg_calls
from calls
where [datetime] >= '20180101'
and dialednumberid = 1234;
```

Comment: apaologies tagged this as mysql when I as looking for answers for sql server ...  so this query doesnt seem to work

Comment: For SQL Server the function is called `DATEDIFF`, `NOW` is `GETDATE`, ANSI date literals are not supported, names are quoted with brackets and division of integers supresses the decimals.

Comment: how can also get max number of calls per 5 min interval

Comment: This is a bit difficult. For instance if I look at 1:00-1:05, 1:05-1:10, ... I may get a maximum of five calls, but if I look at 1:01-1:06, 1:06-1:11, ... I may suddenly get a maximum of ten calls or only two calls. So how do you want to define the five minute interval? Probably look at each record/time and count the recods that took place the five minutes until then, and from all these counts take the maximum.

Comment: Indeed I would just look at the higest number at the 5 minute interval only

Comment: I am telling you that "five minute interval" is ambiguous. It may be a fixed interval, like from minute 0 to 5 then to 10 then to 15, ..., or a floating interval. I suppose you want the floating interval, i.e. no matter when some five minutes got the maximum number of calls. (Could be 2018-10-17 14:03:34.08976 to 2018-10-17 14:08:34.08975 for instance.) Then, as I said, take each record and count the calls since five minutes before it.

Answer (score 0):

This forces the call time into 5 minute intervals.  Use 'count' and 'group by' on these intervals.  Using DateTime as a column name is confusing

```sql
SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, CAST(DATEPART(MINUTE, [DateTime] AS INTEGER)%5 * - 1,CAST(FORMAT([DateTime], 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm') AS DATETIME)) AS CallInterval, COUNT(*)
FROM Calls
GROUP BY DATEADD(MINUTE, CAST(DATEPART(MINUTE, [DateTime]) AS INTEGER)%5 * - 1,CAST(FORMAT([DateTime], 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm') AS DATETIME))
```